# why is .text section on disc and in ram different?

Tags: c++, windows, executable, loader, relocation

I have a program lets call it "SampleApplication" (only 1 exe file). I'm going through this program's .text section in 2 ways

1. Openinig the file "SampleApplication.exe" from other program, going through headers, locating .text section and writting the data byte by byte to a file.
2. Running SampleApplication.exe which has instructions to get its module pointer, go through headers to find it's .text section, and print this section byte by byte to other file.

Now when I compile the applications in 64 bit mode those files are identical - bytes written are the same. **BUT when I compile in 32bit mode** some bytes are different. I have reasons (described below) to believe that those bytes are parts of addresses. My question is why they are different?

Other informations I can provide:

1. Always bytes 64(dec) and 65(dec) (on disc) are changed to some n and n+1 respectively when program is in ram. Example:

Run program

```
a) 64 -> 5, 65 -> 6;
```

another program execution

```
b) 64 -> 5, 65 -> 6;  // bytes are the same
```

Recompile sampleApplication, run it again

```
c) 64 -> 17, 65 -> 18;   // or 31, 32 or 34, 35 or many other combinations
```

2. I checked with disassembly what those bytes represent. They seem to represent the memory address. For example bytes

in ram (notice little endianess)

```
68 60 24 05 00
push (052460)
```

are on disc:

```
68 60 24 40 00
push (402460)
```

(40 is hex for 64)

Anyone can tell me with details what is happening? I really need a deep understanding of this mechanism.

Comment: Address Space Layout Randomization? Can be deactivated.

Comment: I deactivated it and still the same 'problem'

Comment: Address fix-ups.  IIRC 64 bit does not need them and 32 bit does.  Decode some of the instructions and see what they are or just debug the program and look at the assembler.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the "Address fix-ups. IIRC 64 bit does not need them and 32 bit does"?

Comment: @RichardCritten if you could make it into an answer I would be happy to mark it as best answer.